# Setting string to be sql type of "varchar" instead of "nvarchar"

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, schemaexport

I have the following mapping:

```
public class LogEntryMap
{
    public LogEntryMap()
    {
        Map.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Context).CustomSqlType("varchar").Length(512);
    }
}
```

However, using `SchemaExport` to generate the database in SQL Server 2008, the script generated ignores the length so in effect it ends up being a `varchar` with length of 1:

```
create table OV_SAC.dbo.[LogEntry] (
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   Context varchar null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

`.CustomSqlType("varchar 512")` throws an exception. And without defining the `CustomSqlType`, strings are mapped to `nvarchar` (which does respect the `Length` property).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `.CustomType("AnsiString")` instead of default `"String"` and NHibernate will use `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 17):

If you wanted ***all*** of your strings to be mapped to varchar instead of nvarchar you could consider using a convention:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ensures that all of our strings are stored as varchar instead of nvarchar.
/// </summary>
public class OurStringPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Property.PropertyType == typeof (string))
            instance.CustomType("AnsiString");
    }
}
```

You mappings could then go back to a simple mapping:

```
Map(x => x.Context);
```

Just make sure you remember to tell Fluent NH to use the convention:

```
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure();
        Fluently
            .Configure(configuration)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<Widget>()
                .Conventions.Add<OurStringPropertyConvention>()
                )
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Great!! Now, what if I want ALL my properties as varchar, except one? Can I override the CustomType for that entity in the mapping without being overwritten by the convention?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli: yes you can. Conventions only set the defaults. If you use ansi-string convention, and then make a specific column mapping to have i.e. `.CustomType<FooBar>`, it will work just like you'd expect.

Answer (score 8):

Doh.

```
Map(x => x.Context).CustomSqlType("varchar (512)");

create table OV_SAC.dbo.[LogEntry] (
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
   Context varchar (512) null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We found using the "CustomType("AnsiString")" option does prevent it from using the nvarchar, however, it  sets the field length of 8000 for a column that is specified as varchar(30).  The 8000 varchar is much faster than 4000 nvarchar, but it is still causing huge problems with sql server overhead.

Comment: So have you tried: Map(x => x.Context).CustomSqlType("varchar (30)");