# Error in search with like

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

I have a table in a Firebird database

```
CREATE TABLE CIDADE (
CID_CD              SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CID_DS              CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CID_UF              CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
CID_DISTANCIA_SEDE  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CID_CD_ALTERNATIVO  INTEGER NOT NULL,
CID_DT_LK           DATE NOT NULL);
```

I'm doing a query using LINQ with table columns and I'm getting the error in the CHAR type columns:

> arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation string right truncation

Identifying the problem, I realized that the size of type String fields are beyond the limits of the field. I do not understand this, because I mapped the correct length constraints on these fields.

Follows my code:

```
public IQueryable<Cidade> Pesquisar(Cidade cidade)
{
    string uf = cidade.UF; // "SP" for example
    var query = pctxContexto.Cidade.Where(c=> c.UF.Contains(uf));
    return query;
}
```

Mapping:

```
// Table Mapping
ToTable("CIDADE");

//Chave primária
HasKey(t => new { t.Codigo });

//Propriedades
Property(t => t.Codigo).HasColumnName("CID_CD");

Property(t => t.Descricao)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(20)
    .HasColumnType("Char")
    .HasColumnName("CID_DS");

Property(t => t.UF)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(2)
    .HasColumnType("Char")
    .HasColumnName("CID_UF");

Property(t => t.DistanciaSede)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnType("Smallint")
    .HasColumnName("CID_DISTANCIA_SEDE");

Property(t => t.Codigo_Alternativo)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnType("Int")
    .HasColumnName("CID_CD_ALTERNATIVO");
```

How can I solve this problem? Why is it occurring?

Comment: maybe you should change the column type for your char fields from varchar to char since that is what they actually are. I am not sure if it is the problem, but I would say it is a pretty good guess.

Comment: I realized this change and the error persists.

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken, the `.Where(c=> c.UF.Contains(uf)` is translated to `WHERE c.UF LIKE ?` and the parameter has value `"%SP%"`, which is 4 characters.

The problem is that Firebird describes and only accepts parameters with lengths up to the declared length of the field, which is 2 characters. So using a value with length 4 will fail with a string truncation error. For assignment that would be acceptable, but for comparison (and especially for `LIKE` or `SIMILAR TO`) this is highly annoying.

The normal workaround would be to cast the parameter to a longer type, but I am not sure if there is a way to do that when using Entity Framework. The only other workaround is to define columns longer than is strictly necessary for the data.

The related Firebird improvement tickets are:

- [CORE-251](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/582)
- [CORE-3559](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/1361)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably an issue related to encoding. Try the following mapping:

```
Property(t => t.UF)
    .IsRequired()
    .IsUnicode(false)            // <--- 
    .HasMaxLength(2)
    .HasColumnType("Varchar")
    .HasColumnName("CID_UF");
```

Another option (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681001/2642204)) is to use `"AnsiString"` custom type:

```
Property(t => t.UF)
    .IsRequired()
    .CustomType("AnsiString")    // <--- 
    .HasMaxLength(2)
    .HasColumnType("Varchar")
    .HasColumnName("CID_UF");
```